# iCloud Drive Favorites on iCloud.com?

Tags: icloud, web-browser, bookmarks

With the new iCloud.com, is there a way to add a folder within iCloud Drive to the "Favorites" sidebar, so that it is accessible when one accesses iCloud Drive on an internet browser?  Currently, only the "Downloads" folder is listed there.

I tried adding the folder as a "Favorite" on my iPhone, and it is listed there as such, but not when I access iCloud.com drive on my browser.

Is there any way to get the Favorites menu in iCloud.com drive to show other folders as favorites?  Or to be able to bookmark and access a folder in iCloud drive directly?  Thanks.

Comment: Apparently there isn't!

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a way to add a folder to favourites from the web interface. Here's a workaround though. You can add a folder to favourites on iOS, and that configuration change will be synced to the web interface.
https://osxdaily.com/2017/10/13/add-folders-favorites-ios-files/

Comment: I can confirm that adding favorites on my iPhone also immediately showed them on iCloud.com after refreshing

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but the Favorites on iCloud Drive in my internet browser remains, stubbornly unchanged.  To be clear, I am using iCloud.com on Microsoft Edge, on a Windows computer.  Perhaps the cases where it works is an Apple computer or Safari...